# spring batch and spring cloud starter task : expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager, springCloudTransactionManager

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-cloud-task

I'm using spring cloud starter task and deployerPartitionHandler for spring batch remote partitioning job.

Now, When I'm trying to stop a running job using `jobOperator.stop()` method spring batch is throwing

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinationException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager, springCloudTransactionManager
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please share your code and the full stack trace to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: Hey Mahmoud, I solved that issue by creating a primary bean of transactionManager. Also one more thing how can we get the logs of master and each worker nodes and store then in db?

Comment: In case of deployerPartitionHandler

Comment: The deployer partition handler will launch workers as separate tasks (JVMs), so you should be able to fetch their logs as regular apps.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine yeah I got the logs of worker nodes in the custom path by adding spring.cloud.deployer.local.working-directories-root in application.properties file.  Now    1) for each job, is Master node is also launched as a separate JVM?      2) if one of the worker node JVM is failed due to system crash or worker JVM is not launched due to server port issue, the job status remains STARTED even though rest of the nodes have completed their task, is there any way to mark this job as Failed if any of the worker node fails?

Comment: 1) typically yes 2) In that case, you need to update the meta-data tables manually (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#aborting-a-job).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thank you for your help! I'm able to get the worker logs by extending LocalTaskLauncher class,  however couldn't locate the master logs. Can you help me with this, please?